# "Ionic serve" error

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Running `ionic serve` on my ionic app in the command line throws this error:

[image: ionic serve error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common error. Ionic CLI version 2.1.7 is unstable. So uninstall ionic: `npm uninstall -g ionic` and install version 2.0.0:  `npm install -g ionic@2.0.0`.

It works fine.